# Get method name as String, strong typed (C#)

Tags: c#, string, methods

Is there a way to get the name of a method as text, strongly typed?

```
    private void Do()
{

}

private Something ReturnSomething()
{
   return new Something();
}

private void GenerateCode()
{
  // ----------------
  // Do().GetName;
  // ReturnSomething().GetName;
  // ----------------
  // How to do this?
}
```

I tried something like `Do().ToString();` or by using `Reflection`, but I couldn't find something that worked.

Comment: One option is `nameof(Do)`.

Comment: why do you want to do that?. Do().ToString() wont work as Do() is void and does not return nothing

Comment: which .NET Framework?

Comment: @Mong Zhu, .Net 5.0

Comment: @NicoRiff, I'm writing a method that will generate code, and I prefer not to write "Do()" weakly typed, in case the method is renamed later, the code generator will fail because there is no link to the original method.

Comment: I don't recall .NET 5.0 existing yet.

Comment: I mean the latest .NET with C# 5.0 :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the nameof operator

```
string name = nameof(Do);
```